# How do I change portions of a custom theme?

Tags: themes, spacemacs

I'm using one of the pre-defined custom themes that come bundled with Spacemacs (zenburn).

How can I modify specific portions of the theme, for example just change the font color used for comments ?

Comment: Are you sure you mean **color** theme and not **custom** theme? If you are not using the 3rd-party `color-theme.el` then you probably mean custom theme. In that case, please edit your question accordingly. See [Color and Custom Themes](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ColorAndCustomThemes).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I favor using `custom-theme-set-faces` to redefine how the theme displays a particular face, e.g.,

```el
(custom-theme-set-faces
 'zenburn
 '(font-lock-comment-face ((t (:foreground "#DFAF8F"))))
 '(font-lock-comment-delimiter-face ((t (:foreground "#DFAF8F")))))
```

For the specific case of `zenburn`, the theme itself defines various colors and a macro in which those are bound to variable names, so you can write the above as:

```el
(zenburn-with-color-variables
  (custom-theme-set-faces
   'zenburn
   `(font-lock-comment-face ((t (:foreground ,zenburn-orange))))
   `(font-lock-comment-delimiter-face ((t (:foreground ,zenburn-orange))))))
```

Comment: where are you supposed to write this piece of code ? in `.spacemacs` ?

Comment: No idea, sorry; I don't use Spacemacs.  In principle though, all you need to do is cause the code to be evaluated sometime after the `zenburn` theme has been loaded.

Comment: Note: as of Emacs 27, you have to set `custom--inhibit-theme-enable` to nil for this to work https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/52804/12381

Answer (score 9):

In spacemacs, install the layer `theming`, see https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/tree/master/layers/%2Bthemes/theming

For example, I have the following snipped in the `dotspacemacs/user-init` of my `.spacemacs` to adjust the background and linenumber color of the gruvbox and the solarized-light theme:

```
  (setq theming-modifications '(
    ;; requires the theming layer
    (gruvbox
       (default :background "#1D2021" :foreground "#fdf4c1")
       (linum :background "#000000" :foreground "#878787")
       (fringe  :background "#000000")
       (linum-relative-current-face :inherit (shadow default) :background "#3C3836" :foreground "#ff0000")
       (font-lock-comment-face :slant italic)
    )
    (solarized-light
     (linum :background "#DBCDA7" :foreground "#40371F")
       (fringe :background "#DBCDA7")
       (font-lock-comment-face :slant italic)
       )
))
```

Answer (score 4):

I added advice to the load-theme function to override certain faces - that way you can continue to use load-theme as normal to select a theme and it'll apply the overrides automatically.

```
(defadvice load-theme (after theme-set-overrides activate)
  "Set override faces for different custom themes."
  (dolist (theme-settings theme-overrides)
    (let ((theme (car theme-settings))
          (faces (cadr theme-settings)))
      (if (member theme custom-enabled-themes)
          (dolist (face faces)
            (custom-theme-set-faces theme face))))))

(defcustom theme-overrides nil
  "Association list of override faces to set for different custom themes.")

(defun alist-set (alist-symbol key value)
  "Set VALUE of a KEY in ALIST-SYMBOL."
  (set alist-symbol
        (cons (list key value) (assq-delete-all key (eval alist-symbol)))))

; override some settings of the ample-flat theme
(alist-set 'theme-overrides 'ample-flat '(
                                          (default ((t (:background "gray12" :foreground "#bdbdb3"))))
                                          (mode-line ((t (:background "cornsilk4" :foreground "#222" :inherit 'variable-pitch))))
                                          (outline-2 ((t (:inherit font-lock-keyword-face)))) ; blueish
                                          (outline-3 ((t (:inherit font-lock-comment-face)))) ; brownish
                                          (outline-4 ((t (:inherit font-lock-string-face)))) ; orangeish
                                          (org-table ((t (:inherit fixed-pitch :height 0.7 :foreground "#887"))))
                                          (org-formula ((t (:inherit org-table :foreground nil))))
                                          ))
```

It works, and it would be nice to have as part of the interface, but it's probably simplest to just make a function for each theme that you use and call custom-theme-set-faces after loading it -

```
(defun ample-flat ()
  (interactive)
  (mapc #'disable-theme custom-enabled-themes) ; clear any existing themes
  (load-theme 'ample-flat t)
  (custom-theme-set-faces 'ample-flat 
                          '(default ((t (:background "gray12" :foreground "#bdbdb3"))))
                          '(mode-line ((t (:background "cornsilk4" :foreground "#222" :inherit 'variable-pitch))))
                          '(outline-2 ((t (:inherit font-lock-keyword-face)))) ; blueish
                          '(outline-3 ((t (:inherit font-lock-comment-face)))) ; brownish
                          '(outline-4 ((t (:inherit font-lock-string-face)))) ; orangeish
                          '(org-table ((t (:inherit fixed-pitch :height 0.7 :foreground "#887"))))
                          '(org-formula ((t (:inherit org-table :foreground nil))))
                          ))

(ample-flat)
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier for you to just use <kbd>SPC SPC</kbd> `custom-theme-visit-theme`, find `gruvbox`,  make your edits there and then just place `(load-file "~/.emacs.d/gruvbox-theme.el")` in your `dotspacemacs/user-config` function.

Answer (score 0):

Example of what I did to edit `spacemacs-dark`, removing a couple of bolds I don't like:

```lisp
  ;; on dotspacemacs/user-config:

  ;; configure spacemacs-dark theme, specifically removing bolds
  (let
      ((func "#d75fd7")
       (keyword "#4f97d7")
       (type "#ce537a"))

    (custom-theme-set-faces
     'spacemacs-dark
     `(font-lock-function-name-face ((t (:foreground ,func :inherit normal))))
     `(font-lock-keyword-face ((t (:foreground ,keyword :inherit normal))))
     `(font-lock-type-face ((t (:foreground ,type :inherit normal))))
     )
    )
```