# How to customize org-agenda-* faces in .emacs file?

Tags: init-file, faces, themes, customize, use-package

I am trying to customize org-agenda-* faces such as org-agenda-date, 
org-agenda-date-today, and org-agenda-date-weekend in my .emacs file. Normally,
I install the use-package package to lazily load each package to reduce emacs init time. At first, in the code below I call set-face-attribute to customize those faces, but it is in vain.

```
(use-package org-mode
    :config
    (set-face-attribute 'org-agenda-date-today nil
                        :foreground "#FFFFEF"
                        :background "#3F3F3F"
                        :bold t))
```

Next, I found that other emacs users invoke the defface function to customize those faces instead, and it does also work in my setup.

```
(use-package zenburn-theme
    :ensure t
    :config
    (load-theme 'zenburn t)
    (defface org-agenda-date
       '((t (:foreground "#BFEBBF"
             :background "#3F3F3F"
             :bold nil)))
    "Face used in agenda for weekdays."
      :group 'org-faces))
```

Edit: Lawlist's comment reminds me of using M-x customize-face to customize these faces and it works.

Between the three approaches defface, set-face-attribute, and customize-face, which one is the best way to customize faces? In case you have an alternative way to customize them, please share your approach here.

Thanks,

Comment: Here is a solution to customize select faces of the zenburn theme that does *not* utilize `use-package`:  http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/17962/2287

Comment: @lawlist Thank you. That's another solution, and your answer also reminds me of the other method to customize the faces I will edit my question in a few minutes.

Comment: I used to use `set-face-attribute` and now use `face-spec-set` but I don't know the best way to do this…

Comment: Use Customize (in this case `M-x customize-face`). It is far more fail-safe than trying to simulate its effect yourself using Lisp in your init file. It just works - does the right thing. And for more hygiene and safety, use a separate file for Customize-generated code - see variable `custom-file`.

Comment: @Drew Personally, I don't like the customize interface much, and I much prefer to break my settings down into small files with comments (which I believe customize would destroy, even with the excellent `custom-file`).

Answer (score 1):

As [suggested by amitp in a comment](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/29970/how-to-customize-org-agenda-faces-in-emacs-file?newreg=890b5a145a4e4296a0f33d16631a65d6#comment46072_29970), try:

- [`set-face-attribute`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Attribute-Functions.html#index-set_002dface_002dattribute-4600);

  e.g. `(set-face-attribute 'foo nil :weight 'bold :slant 'italic)`
- [`face-spec-set`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Defining-Faces.html#index-face_002dspec_002dset-4593)