# Accidental yank or paste into org buffer

Tags: org-mode, osx, copy-paste, yank

EDIT: I closed and reopened Emacs again and the same behavior happened. But this time the text inserted was from my last kill or `M-w`—`(add-hook 'before-save-hook 'time-stamp)`—to copy it to the system clipboard for the purposes of writing the last lines of my question. So it appears to be more a Mac OS X copy-paste thing than a problem with `org-special-edit`. Still annoying and any help would be appreciated!

ORIGINAL QUESTION: This might be something of a longshot. I am using Emacs 25.0.95 with Org 8.2.10 on OS X Yosemite. I have my init file in an `.org` file. Lately I have begun to find the contents of org source buffers (the ones that you open at point with `C-c '` and save and exit with `C-c '`) make their way into another location in the original org buffer. Just now it happened after making a few edits to my configuration of `zenburn-theme`. I hit `C-c '` for `org-edit-special`, set up `zenburn-theme` how I wanted it, and hit `C-c '` again. Then I closed Emacs to reload the init and completely refresh the way the was theme displaying. So I started Emacs up again, and it loads everything OK; yet when I opened my init file again, I find that the file has been somehow edited—in fact, the text I saved with `org-edit-special` has inserted itself towards the top of my init file. So where originally I had this—

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :tangle yes
  ;; set up 'package
  (require 'package)
  (setq package-enable-at-startup nil)
  (add-to-list 'package-archives
                '("melpa-stable" . "http://stable.melpa.org/packages/") t)
  (add-to-list 'package-archives
                '("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/") t)
  (package-initialize)

  ;; bootstrap 'use-package
  (unless (package-installed-p 'use-package)
    (package-refresh-contents)
    (package-install 'use-package))
  (eval-when-compile
    (require 'use-package))
  ;; load 'use-package dependencies: 'bind-key and 'diminish
  (require 'bind-key)                     ; (bundled with `use-package')
  (use-package diminish
    :ensure t)
#+END_SRC
```

—the contents of my last `org-edit-special` buffer (from last session)—

```
(use-package zenburn-theme
  :ensure t
  :config
  ;; customize zenburn faces (http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/17962)
  (zenburn-with-color-variables
    (custom-theme-set-faces
     'zenburn
     ;; change some org-mode faces to make org-blocks more legible à la leuven-theme
     ;; (https://github.com/bbatsov/zenburn-emacs/pull/175/commits/0c27021b8708464236b78a40546971279d5ae404)
     `(org-block                   ((t (:foreground ,zenburn-fg :background ,zenburn-bg+1))))
     `(org-block-background        ((t (:background ,zenburn-bg+1))))
     `(org-block-begin-line        ((t (:foreground ,zenburn-fg :background ,zenburn-bg+05 :underline ,zenburn-bg))))
     `(org-block-end-line          ((t (:foreground ,zenburn-fg :background ,zenburn-bg+05 :overline ,zenburn-bg))))))
  (load-theme 'zenburn t))
```

—have been yanked or pasted somehow such that I get this:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :tangle yes
  ;; set up 'package
  (requir(use-package zenburn-theme
    :ensure t
    :config
    ;; customize zenburn faces (http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/17962)
    (zenburn-with-color-variables
      (custom-theme-set-faces
       'zenburn
       ;; change some org-mode faces to make org-blocks more legible à la leuven-theme
;; (https://github.com/bbatsov/zenburn-emacs/pull/175/commits/0c27021b8708464236b78a40546971279d5ae404)
       `(org-block                   ((t (:foreground ,zenburn-fg :background ,zenburn-bg+1))))
       `(org-block-background        ((t (:background ,zenburn-bg+1))))
       `(org-block-begin-line        ((t (:foreground ,zenburn-fg :background ,zenburn-bg+05 :underline ,zenburn-bg))))
       `(org-block-end-line          ((t (:foreground ,zenburn-fg :background ,zenburn-bg+05 :overline ,zenburn-bg))))))
       (load-theme 'zenburn t))e 'package)
  (setq package-enable-at-startup nil)
  (add-to-list 'package-archives
                '("melpa-stable" . "http://stable.melpa.org/packages/") t)
  (add-to-list 'package-archives
                '("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/") t)
  (package-initialize)

  ;; bootstrap 'use-package
  (unless (package-installed-p 'use-package)
    (package-refresh-contents)
    (package-install 'use-package))
  (eval-when-compile
    (require 'use-package))
  ;; load 'use-package dependencies: 'bind-key and 'diminish
  (require 'bind-key)                     ; (bundled with `use-package')
  (use-package diminish
    :ensure t)
#+END_SRC
```

In other words, unless I am mistaken, the text saved with `org-edit-special` from an earlier session has survived into a new Emacs session and yanked itself into my buffer without my doing anything. It's annoying because, unless I am vigilant, my init will be broken next time I launch Emacs. Does this have something to do with org-mode or is a kill-ring problem? or does it have something to do with how the file is saving? (I have `(add-hook 'before-save-hook 'time-stamp)` in my init in order to automatically update the date in the `Time-stamp: <>` format.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that [emacs-dashboard](https://github.com/rakanalh/emacs-dashboard) was the culprit. It's a wonderful package, but disabling it fixed the problem.